# Equivalent definitions for strictly positive elements

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

We have two usual definitions for strictly positive elements in C*-algebras: Let $A$ be a C*-algebra

> **Definition (a)** [MURPHY, *C$^*$-algebras and Operator Theory*] An element $a\in A_+$ is said to be *strictly positive* if $\overline{aAa}=A$, that is, the hereditary subalgebra generated by $a$ is dense in $A$.

One can easily show that the following equivalence holds:
$$\overline{aA}=A\iff\overline{Aa}=A\iff\overline{aAa}$$

> **Definition (b)** [TAKESAKI, *Theory of Operator Algebras I*] An element $a\in A$ is said to be *strictly positive* if $\tau(a)>0$ for every state $\tau\in A^*$. Equivalently, $a$ is strictly positive if $\tau(a)>0$ for every nonzero positive lineaer functional $\tau$ on $A$.

In his book *Operator Algebras*, Blackadar says that it can be shown that these two definitions are equivalent, using Hahn-Banach and the usual results about extension of positive functionals. I've already shown that $(a)\Rightarrow (b)$, so the other implication is the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\overline{aAa}\subsetneq A$. Choose $b\geq0$ in $A\setminus\overline{aAa}$ and use Hanh-Banach to construct a functional with $f(b)=1$ and $f(aca)=0$ for all $c\in A$. This functional is a linear combination of four states (see II.6.3.4 in Blackadar): at least one of them, say $f_1$, will satisfy that $f_1(b)>0$; by the Jordan Decomposition, we also have that $f_1(aca)=0$ for all $c\in A$ (because of the uniqueness of the Jordan decomposition, the Jordan Decomposition of $f|_{aAa}$ agrees with the Jordan decomposition of $f$).

But then $f(a^3)=0$. Using  Kadison's Inequality twice,
$$
0\leq f(a)^2\leq f(a^2)\leq f(a^4)^{1/2}\leq\|a\|^{1/2}\,f(a^3)^{1/2}=0,
$$
so $f_1(a)=0$.

---

**Edit:** this argument as written is wrong (concretely, the part about the Jordan decomposition of the restriction; for instance, it is perfectly possible for a state to not be a state when restricted to a certain subalgebra, and the uniqueness of the Jordan decomposition relies on a condition on the norm). The idea can still be made to work, but it requires more machinery. Eventually I will type it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't your arguments with the dimension of $aAa$. Could you please explain this a little more?

Comment: You are right. I have changed the argument a little, using the uniqueness of the Jordan decomposition.