# Equivalent definitions of 'strictly positive' in C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742052/equivalent-definitions-for-strictly-positive-elements) shows that the definition of Takesaki implies the definition of Murphy. However, I don't see why the converse is true. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $aAa$ is dense and $\tau(a)=0$, then for any $b\in A_+$ you have$$0\leq \tau(aba)\leq\|b\|\,\tau(a^2)\leq\|b\|\,\|a\|\,\tau(a)=0.$$ 
As positive elements span $A$, you get $aAa\subset \ker\tau$. By density and continuity, $\tau=0$, a contradiction. So $\tau(a)>0$ for each state $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How did you conclude that $\tau(a^{2})\leq\|a\|\tau(a)$?

Comment: Never mind, I think I understand! Thank you!

Comment: Just in case: $a^2=a^{1/2}aa^{1/2}\leq\|a\|\,a^{1/2}a^{1/2}=\|a\|\,a$.